# Persist accessibility permissions between builds in xcode 13

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, permissions

I am building a window manager that requires the use of the Accessibility API for macOS. My code works fine if I build the app, grant the debug build accessibility permissions in the Security and Privacy panel, and then run my code.  But if I change any code, I have to regrant the permissions manually and it is incredibly laborious to do between each build.

How can I persist the permissions between builds? I see this is an issue elsewhere and I have tried all the tactics I found on Stack Overflow so far.

- [Auto allow access to MacOS accessibility API during development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72271930/auto-allow-access-to-macos-accessibility-api-during-development)
- [MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 Keeps Asking for Accessibility Permission for an App When Launched from XCode 13.2.1 Even After Granting the Permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105103/macos-monterey-12-2-1-keeps-asking-for-accessibility-permission-for-an-app-when)
- [How to prompt for accessibility features in a macOS app (from the AppDelegate)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70814854/how-to-prompt-for-accessibility-features-in-a-macos-app-from-the-appdelegate)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Figures I would solve this right after I post it.

The App needs to be signed with a [certificate following this process to](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev60b6fbbc7) keep continuity between builds.

If your Apple ID is already hooked up to XCode and you have a developer account, I went to the "Signing and Capabilities" section in the App Targets section and updated "Signing Certificate" to "Development".